# Codename one Toolbar command to pop up menu

Tags: codenameone

I have added a command to the right on the toolbar as follows
[image]

Now I when I click on the 3-dot command, I would like to show a button to logout as follows
[image]

I tried with Dialog and InteractionDialog and I am not able to achieve this.  I am looking for some guidance/help to achieve this.  Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try addCommandToOverflowMenu as shown in below

```
Command logoutCommand = new Command("Logout");
toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(logoutCommand);
```